# how can i Bind a Host Path to a named volume in Docker with size limitation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-volume

i need to bind a directory from host to container , i need to limit the amount of data that is generated from a program in the container , for example 5gb, if the program generated 5gb data and reached the limit in the container environment, program be treated like there is no more free space on disk.
i need to have access to this path from host ,
and i need it to only run in container,
as far as i know i can bind a path from host to container with Binds, but this does not have a option to limit the volume size, and a named volume have this option but i cant bind a path from host anymore,
is there a way i can achieve this?

Comment: I might have seen a fuse driver that acts as this kind of overlay, but it'd be a lot lower-overhead to map your container to a host UID with a quota attached for the filesystem at hand.

Comment: Docker on its own doesn't have anything like this.  The closest sort of size limitations are a couple of implementation-specific approaches that limit the total size of Docker space including named volumes (the Docker Desktop VM setup, for example) but Docker doesn't implement disk quotas, especially for bind mounts.